# Solr - return documents that are within the radius of multiple points?

Tags: solr, solr8

I have a set of data, where each entry has a lat/lon coordinate associated with it.

I have the following form:

- textfield that is converted to a lat/lon via geocoding
- 3 select fields, each allowing only a single value, and each value represents a lat/lon coordinate

I would like to return all data that has a lat/lon coordinate within a 50 mile radius of any of the lat/lon points selected in the form. What is the recommended approach to doing this with Solr?

Comment: You can use the field type [latlonpointspatialfield](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/spatial-search.html#latlonpointspatialfield) for indexing lat/lon, and then for querying use the [geofilt](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/spatial-search.html#geofilt) query parser in a filter query (fq). Matching entries within a circle of the given radius around _any_ of the lat/lon points selected means you need one `{!geofilt}` for each point separated by an OR. What have you tried ?

Comment: Hi @EricLavault, thanks for the insight. That's what I ended up needing to do. To make things slightly more complicated I'm doing this through a Drupal module, and they unfortunately have some limiting factors that prevent searching/filtering on more than one location. Fortunately there is a low level mechanism that allows me to alter the Solr query directly before it is issued, and I was able to utilize that method to implement your suggestion. Worked like a charm. If you want to post that as an answer I can give you accepted answer credit.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it helped, thanks for the feedback ! I posted an answer below with a bit more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a field type [`LatLonPointSpatialField`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/spatial-search.html#latlonpointspatialfield) for indexing the lat/lon. coordinates. For example, Solr default configset defines the following in its schema, which is sufficient to enable spatial search :

```
<!-- A specialized field for geospatial search filters and distance sorting. -->
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

> LLPSF supports toggling indexed, stored, docValues, and multiValued.
> LLPSF internally uses a 2-dimensional Lucene "Points" (BDK tree) index
> when "indexed" is enabled (the default). When "docValues" is enabled,
> a latitude and longitudes pair are bit-interleaved into 64 bits and
> put into Lucene DocValues. The accuracy of the docValues data is about
> a centimeter.

Then for querying, use the [`geofilt`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/spatial-search.html#geofilt) query parser in a filter query. Matching entries within a circle of the given radius around any of the (multiple) lat/lon points selected means you need to OR multiple `{!geofilt}` queries, one for each `pt`. Note that the radial distance `d` must be specified in kilometers, eg. :

```
 q=*:*&sfield=coord_p&d=80.4672&fq=({!geofilt pt=x1,y1} OR {!geofilt pt=x2,y2} OR ...)
```